# I am not able to find the xpath of html element

Tags: xpath, element, watir

My application can only be tested in IE, So i tried adding below bookmarklets for finding xpath.

```
javascript:function getNode(node){var nodeExpr=node.tagName;if(!nodeExpr)return null;if(node.id!=''){nodeExpr+="[@id='"+node.id+"']";return "/"+nodeExpr;}var rank=1;var ps=node.previousSibling;while(ps){if(ps.tagName==node.tagName){rank++;}ps=ps.previousSibling;}if(rank>1){nodeExpr+='['+rank+']';}else{var ns=node.nextSibling;while(ns){if(ns.tagName==node.tagName){nodeExpr+='[1]';break;}ns=ns.nextSibling;}}return nodeExpr;}

javascript:function o__o(){var currentNode=document.selection.createRange().parentElement();var path=[];while(currentNode){var pe=getNode(currentNode);if(pe){path.push(pe);if(pe.indexOf('@id')!=-1)break;}currentNode=currentNode.parentNode;}var xpath="/"+path.reverse().join('/');clipboardData.setData("Text", xpath);}o__o();
```

I tried finding xpath of the element in the google.com (I am feeling luckly button) using the above bookmarklets. It returns as *//BODY[@id='gsr']*

But when i tried to find the xpath of the menu element in my web application using the above bookmarklets. It returns as */HTML/BODY*.

My web applications has menu bar in a separate frame.

```
<frameset name="fr" id="fr" border="0" frameBorder="NO" frameSpacing="0" marginwidth="0" >
<frame name="frNav" src="navi.esp" ">
    <html>
    <head>
    .......
    </head>
    <body class="GlobalNavBackground" onload="InitializePage();" onunload="" onresize="DisplayChange()">
    <div id="MainMenu" style="display: none;">
            <div tabIndex="-1" class="ActionMenuDropDown" id="ActionMenu_Registration" onblur="HideDropdown(this);">
                <div class="active" onmouseover="this.className='selected';" onmouseout="this.className='active';" onclick=('/registration.esp?'>
```

How can i access the menu & menu items, in this case? Xpath doesn't work for it.
I am working with watir to automate the process.
Please give your suggestion.

Comment: using xpath with watir is almost always the hard way to do things.  The watir API and object model make it much easier to make sense of the code, and create code that is not brittle and hard to maintain.  See Adam's answer

Comment: Arunsankar - did this solution resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Xpath is tedious and fragile.  I recommend starting with basic HTML tags.  You can access any HTML elements whose parent is the MainMenu div element, in the same way that I have described "divs" below.

```
@browser.frame(:name => "frNav").div(:id => "MainMenu").div.each do |div|
        #for each div element in the MainMenu div, in the frNav frame
    puts div.id
        #write the div id to the console
end
```

You can simplify this for re-use and readibility by assigning values to the parent elements:

```
MenuFrame = @browser.frame(:name => "frNav")
MainMenu = MenuFrame.div(:id => "MainMenu")

MainMenu.div(:id => "ActionMenu_Registration").click
```

Really, all you're looking to do is specify the parent frame and next element (parent/child):

```
browser.frame(:how => what).div(:how => what).element
```